# Adding a new custom input field in order > invoice magento

Tags: magento-1.7

I am trying to add new input field in `sales > order > invoice` . This would be like my reference number. This custom input field should be show in `sales > order >invoice` & `sales > invoice` & when print invoice this custom field need to get showed , New custom grid need to get added , I am currently working with this :

[Jquery](http://www.jquery.zeering.com/LoadAnswers.aspx?q=Magento%20custom%20%E2%80%9Corder%E2%80%9D%20attribute%20/%20admin%20input%20and%20display)

Can some one let me know how i need to proceed for this .

Custom field in admin panel should look like this  : https://i.stack.imgur.com/BaEbb.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's lot of work to do. However, I will try to add some relevant link for you to guide you to right direction.

Follow these great tutorials:

1. [Custom field in order page](http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-create-a-custom-grid-from-scratch/)
2. [Creating Custom grid](http://tutorialsformagento.blogspot.com.au/2014/06/add-custom-fields-to-order-and-quote.html) - Once you add a new table/attribute (in 1) then can add this field to appear in custom grid

In order to add these fields in invoices, you will need to rewrite few `phtml` and `block` classes. Learn rewriting classes [here](http://inchoo.net/magento/overriding-magento-blocks-models-helpers-and-controllers/).

To be able to add this field in print invoice (pdf invoice), you will need to learn magento pdf functions. You can learn [here](http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-add-custom-attribute-to-magentos-pdf-invoice/).

It's lot of work. Hope it will help and good luck.

Comment: Hello  Adarash Thanks , will look on this for the implementation , Do we have any free or paid extension for this .

Comment: Not sure, but I have had successfully implemented this similar requirement before, following those links.